# How can I find the order of a clicked input element among inputs of the same type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Let's say a form has 5 'text' inputs and 3 'radio' inputs. If the user clicks on one of the 'radio' inputs, how can I find the index of that input *among inputs of the same type*? In other words, if the user clicked on the second of the three radio inputs, I'm looking for the result 2.

I've tried the following in jQuery:

```
$("input").click(function(event) {
    alert( $("input").index(event.target) );
}
```

That's close but it returns the index among ALL input results, not just the input type that was clicked on.

NOTE: I don't know what the input type will be before the event is triggered so I'm asking how to narrow down the selector based on the clicked input type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$("input").click(function(event) {
    alert( $("input[type=" +this.type +"]").index(event.target) );
});
```

Comment: Maybe even: `(this.type || 'text')` in case no `type` attribute is set. And as `event.target === this` you can use `index(this)`.

Comment: The solution worked well and thanks for the good comment about adding a default type.

Comment: If the input is omitted, JavaScript returns "text".

Comment: @Emil: Interesting. Didn't know that :)

Comment: @felix It is in HTML5, but it works with older browsers as well, because if they do not understand the input type, text is assumed.

Comment: @Emil: I know that the default type is `text`. That does not mean that one gets this value when accessing `input.type`. But it seems to work, so it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
$('input').click(function () {
    var i = $('input:' + $(this).attr('type')).index(this);
});
```